# Why Do I get 403?

Tags: html, .htaccess

http://dyingghost.tk/avatars/127b36fbd44548351b4653c3ca854817_2.png
Why do I get 403?

my .htaccess is

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
allow from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
order deny,allow
```

Comment: <Files ~ "^\.(htpasswd)$"> so its that?

Comment: I mean rename this .htacess and see if 403 goes away ?

Comment: oh my god, my fault in spelling once again. Thanks